# Как получить все объекты, на которые роль имеет доступ 1С?

Tags: 1с

Как можно получить все объекты, на которые роль имеет доступ с самим доступом (чтение, изменение, ...)?

Сейчас пока есть вариант в цикле перебрать все объекты из `Метаданные`, проверяя каждое право доступа (`Если ПравоДоступа("Просмотр", Документ, Роль) Тогда`). Но может есть какой-нибудь вариант попроще? Например, есть ли что-то подобное - `НужнаяРоль.ОбъектыНаКоторыеЕстьПраваДоступа`?

Comment: На базе какой конфигурации вы работаете?

Comment: Что вы пытаетесь сделать в целом? Опишите задачу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убедитесь что в вашей конфигурации присутствует `РегистрСведений.ПраваРолей` попробуйте так:

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
    ПраваРолей.ОбъектМетаданных КАК ОбъектМетаданных,
    ПраваРолей.Роль КАК Роль,
    ПраваРолей.Изменение КАК Изменение,
    ПраваРолей.Добавление КАК Добавление,
    ПраваРолей.ЧтениеБезОграничения КАК ЧтениеБезОграничения,
    ПраваРолей.ИзменениеБезОграничения КАК ИзменениеБезОграничения,
    ПраваРолей.ДобавлениеБезОграничения КАК ДобавлениеБезОграничения,
    ПраваРолей.Просмотр КАК Просмотр,
    ПраваРолей.Редактирование КАК Редактирование,
    ПраваРолей.ИнтерактивноеДобавление КАК ИнтерактивноеДобавление
ИЗ
    РегистрСведений.ПраваРолей КАК ПраваРолей
ГДЕ
    ПраваРолей.Роль = &Роль
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, действительно помогло. Только есть еще небольшой вопрос. Мне нужно выполнить такой запрос для 200-500 ролей. То есть будет выполняться очень много запросов к базе. Критично ли это? Если да, то можно ли как-то одним запросом вернуть сразу все данные для ролей из массива? Можно ли использовать `ГДЕ ПраваРолей.Роль В (&МассивРолей)`?

Comment: Возможно ли зная массив ролей вернуть с помощью одного запроса массив структур? В каждой структуре ссылка на роль, ссылка на объект метаданных и массив прав доступа на объект у данной роли

Comment: Можно ли использовать 'ГДЕ ПраваРолей.Роль В (&МассивРолей)' ? Да, можно. Единственное Вам потребуется добавить 'УПОРЯДОЧИТЬ ПО Роль'; чтобы при обходе результата запроса данные Роли располагались вместе;

Comment: вернуть с помощью одного запроса массив структур? более распространенной практикой является работа с результатом запроса в виде "плоской таблицы", обход результата и преобразование хоть в структуру, хоть в массив; работа с Результатом запроса вида: Роль, ТаблицаЗначенийПрав; также возможна, но для этого исходные данные должны быть такого вида;